# Is repentance allowed after major signs of end times?

Tags: day-of-judgement, imam-mahdi, end-times

Can disbeliever still repent after noticing the major signs of the end times (before the sun rise from the west)? Will disbelievers be able to notice them?

Answer (score 3):

> I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: Migration will not end until
> repentance ends, and repentance will not end until the sun rises in
> the west.
>
> Sunan Abi Dawud 2479
>
> Grade : Sahih (Al-Albani)

Another:

> Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "He who repents before the sun rises from
> the west, Allah will forgive him".
>
> [Muslim].

Some have argued lately that those hadiths do not mean a literal interpretation none the less which ever position you choose one should never neglect nor stop asking forgiveness.

And Allah (swt) knows best.